# How to Define KPIs for a product solution

Tags: data, data-table, data-product

I have to find certain KPIs for a given product solutions and describe data tables to track those KPIs.

Context:
Our practitioners conduct treatment X in 3 steps with patient, so it leads to 3 appointments:

1. Check to see if treatment X is needed. 2. preparation and 3. actual treatment

Problem:
Too many patients have a positive check and need treatment X, so practitioners often forget to schedule the following appointments. Patients are not treated adequately and our doctors lose potential revenues.

Product solution:
We will automatically send a sms to patients with positive check after their check appointment, with a link to book an appointment for the following step.

Task:
Define KPIs you would want to track to check if this product solution is working well
Describe the data tables you would need engineering to create to track these KPIs

BONUS : Create a rough dashboard draft that you would use to show these KPIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KPIs are linked to your project's objective.

If the aim is to know whether a product works well or not, you can either collect indicators from doctors or patients.

In general, doctors are easier to monitor, as this kind of indicator is useful for them to know the product effects.

Your system should focus on indicators than can provide the doctor to monitor the product's real effect. To ensure that the doctors collect them correctly, it is better to set the most important indicators as mandatory (ex: the next appointment).

Therefore, you need to know KPIs such as:

- General information such as age, weight, etc.
- Linked health indicators at each step.
- Treatment requested by the doctor.
- Result of the treatment in the short and long term.

Then, you should be able to have dashboards from many patients thanks to this data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You have described the solution in detail. But I don't get to understand how the KPIs you have mentioned will help to check if the product solution is working well. So again solution is:                               
- it will automatically send a sms to patients with positive check after their check appointment, with a link to book an appointment for the next step.                          I need to show KPIs to check if the patients are getting the sms link for book the appointment for their treatment. I am think something like their mobile numbers or patient id

Comment: The efficiency of any medication depends on many parameters: a small and thin person with heart problems would not react the same way as a tall one with diabetes for instance. Then, you can ask the patients to book the appointment, but I've said that doctors used to be more regular to collect data and organize appointments. But I don't know enough about your business case. Mobile numbers are also important to send a reminder.

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, it does partially.